# Polymer: Styling specific core submenu icons

Tags: css, css-selectors, polymer, shadow-dom, core-elements

I have a core-menu with a few core-submenus (each is itself an accordion submenu) beneath it. Each submenu has an icon and a label, defined in the submenu's attribute markup. Is there a way I can set different colors for the icon and the label? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

You can see what I've tried below.

```
<style>
    core-submenu {
        color: red;
    }
    core-submenu::shadow [icon="maps:local-hospital"] { 
        color: blue; 
    }
    core-submenu::shadow [icon="editor:attach-money"] { 
        color: green; 
    }
</style>

<core-menu>
    <core-submenu icon="maps:local-hospital" label="Benefits">
            <core-item label="Hospitals"></core-item>
            <core-item label="Clinics"></core-item>
    </core-submenu>
     <core-submenu icon="editor:attach-money" label="Money">
            <core-item label="Banks"></core-item>
            <core-item label="ATMs"></core-item>
    </core-submenu>
</core-menu>
```

Note that I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771587/polymer-trouble-styling-the-core-submenu) post on core-submenu styling and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734090/polymer-core-submenu-styling-in-firefox) post on core-submenu styling in Firefox but found neither helpful for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771587/polymer-trouble-styling-the-core-submenu) post that you link to:

> Each core-submenu includes a `core-item` in its shadow DOM, which is used to display the title and icon for the submenu.
>
> The item itself contains a `core-icon` in its shadow root, with an ID of icon

Your selector currently targets an element with the `icon` attribute within the `core-submenu`'s shadow tree. That's not correct, since

- the `icon` attribute is on the `core-submenu` element itself, and
- you are trying to target a `core-icon` element, not an element with the `icon` attribute.

You need to combine the attribute selector with the `core-submenu` type selector and its `::shadow` pseudo-element, and target the icon within the submenu *item*'s shadow tree with an additional `::shadow` pseudo-element, like so:

```css
core-submenu {
    color: red;
}
core-submenu[icon="maps:local-hospital"]::shadow core-item::shadow #icon {
    color: blue; 
}
core-submenu[icon="editor:attach-money"]::shadow core-item::shadow #icon {
    color: green;
}
```